# Why did the bartender not agree with Mark?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-invention-of-lying

In [The Invention of Lying](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1058017/), Mark and Anna went to a hotel,

In this scene the bartender does not agree with Mark:

> Mark: They look fine to me.
>
> Bartender: Well, you're stupid.

See here the bartender should reply "Yes, to me also" because of Mark's **Fantasy Power**, but he replies with "Well, you're stupid." Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark is stating an opinion, not lying about a fact. So, the bartender disagrees with his opinion, and shares one of his own.

Mark's power is just to lie, and people there just take it at face value.

Comment: To add to this, if Mark had said 'They are fine', then the Bartender would have agreed. 'They look fine' is giving an opinion, 'They are fine' is stating a fact/lie.